# how to solve an easy look integration and how..please..step by step

Tags: integration

Consider
\begin{align}
y = \int \sin(e^ x) \ dx
\end{align}
How do I integrate that, I know the result is $y'=\sin(e^x)$ but why?

So, I can't do it straight away, so I've got to use either substitution or integration by parts, as it is a composition I would say substitution but I don't see any relation between $\cos$ and $e^x$ ...any detailed help about how to proceed? thanks!

Comment: I edited your formatting. Please check, whether it is still correct.

Comment: With the formatting change I'm now unsure, do you want to integrate that or differentiate $y$?

Comment: @Jim: All I edited was replacing  y = ∫sin(e^x)dx with the Latex formula and putting dollar signs around y'=sin(e^x).

Comment: Yea, I just meant that the new formatting made me read the question more carefully.

Comment: Okay, sorry my bad!

Comment: The question seems very confused.  When students are asked to _differentiate_ a function defined by something like $y=\int\sin(e^x)\,dx$, it is not unusual for them to think they've been asked to integrate something.  But if you'd been asked to integrate something, the answer would not be $y'=\sin(e^x)$.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my old answer for the following reason: While you can do a substitution the resulting integral can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions.  Trying to evaluate that integral symbolically is essentially impossible.

Given that your book says the answer is $y' = \sin(e^x)$ I think the problem is to take the derivative of $y$, not to evaluate that integral.

To take the derivative of $y$ you use the fact that without bounds the symbols $\int f(x)dx$ just mean "the function whose derivative is $f(x)$".  Hence if we take the derivative of the function whose derivative is $f(x)$ we get $f(x)$.  Hence $y' = \sin(e^x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$I=\int \sin(e^x) \, dx$

Let $t=e^x$

$$I=\int \frac {\sin(t)}{t} \, dt= \operatorname{Si}(e^x)+C$$

As far as I know, there is no solution in terms of elementary functions.